# Node JS - Winston is not logging anything to log file

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

Here is code sample:

```
   var winston = require('winston');
   var loggerNew = new (winston.Logger)({
   transports: [
       new winston.transports.File({filename: 'all-logs.log'})
   ],
   exceptionHandlers: [
      new winston.transports.File({filename: 'exceptions.log'})
   ]
   });
```

I am using winston module for logging expecption. But it is not writing anything to file. Please give advice!

Comment: I run your code without any problem and it's created log file. how do you log ?

Comment: How do you run your code? the file name is created relative to the process location, try changing the filename to `require("path").join(__dirname,"all-logs.log")`

Comment: @ParhamAlvani : I am using the same code which I posted here. 
Can you tell me your node version and winston version?

Answer (score 0):

```
winston.exceptions.handle(
  new winston.transportsConsole(),
  new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'logs/test.log' })
);

throw new Error('Exception Handler');
```

Try this.